# Convert Date to Financial Quarter in Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013, financial

I am having some real trouble trying to figure out a nice way to get some SQL in my access database to create a Financial Quarter result based on a date in the format `dd/mm/yyyy` (UK).  I have a Column called 'Date' in the table 'DimDate' and I have a column called 'FinancialQuarter' within the same table.
So I essentially want the SQL to work out the following:

If the month is between 1 and 3 equals Q1,
If the month is between 4 and 6 equals Q2,
If the month is between 7 and 9 equals Q3,
If the month is between 10 and 12 equals Q4,

I have some basic SQL skills but I am no expert.  I found a post in StackOverflow similar to this question however I made no progress from it.  The SQL code they used which I modified was as follows:

```
SELECT
Date,
CASE
    WHEN MONTH(Date) BETWEEN 1  AND 3  THEN convert(char(4), YEAR(Date) - 1) + 'Q1'
    WHEN MONTH(Date) BETWEEN 4  AND 6  THEN convert(char(4), YEAR(Date) - 1) + 'Q2'
    WHEN MONTH(Date) BETWEEN 7  AND 9  THEN convert(char(4), YEAR(Date) - 0) + 'Q3'
    WHEN MONTH(Date) BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN convert(char(4), YEAR(Date) - 0) + 'Q4'
END AS FinancialQuarter 
FROM
DimDate
```

My code does not work at all, and its probably completely wrong,  any help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks
James.

Comment: Access SQL does not support the `CASE WHEN` construct. The corresponding mechanism in Access SQL is the [Switch()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-Function-d750c10d-0c8e-444c-9e63-f47504f9e379) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realised your using access

```
DatePart('q',[date])
```

DATEPART QUARTER

```
SELECT date, DATEPART(QUARTER, date) as FinancialQuarter 
FROM DimDate
```

Comment: Hi Matt, when I run that I am prompted to enter parameter value for Quarter.  What would I enter here?  Thanks for your post.